# Sending byte data over Websockets (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, websocket

Is it possible to send byte data (array) over Websockets or only strings?

So any ideas why ArrayBuffer doesnt work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API isn't finalized, but you should be able to use an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer) (a JavaScript typed array).

Comment: How to add 1 byte to ArrayBuffer? arr[i] = 128; puts in array "128"(0x31 0x32 0x38). arr[i].push(128); same.

Comment: What browser? `arr[i]` seems to work fine in Chrome 15. At any rate, as described on the [JavaScript typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays) page, you should probably be working with a _view_, and not the raw array. But this is really a separate issue from your original question, so you should ask a separate question if you're having trouble.

Comment: sockets.push(new WebSocket("ws://"+serverip+":"+serverport));
sendbuf[id] = new ArrayBuffer();
sendbuf[id][0] = 128;
sockets[id].send(sendbuf[id]);

This send "128" not 128; (Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Blob objects claim to offer this functionality, but they're only supported on a few browsers to my understanding.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets/WebSockets_reference/WebSocket

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Blob